# Best practices for running a thread to retrieve the correct connection string in the DAL

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I created a class in my project that opens a thread and continuously polls a connection, if the connection is closed it retrieves a connection string to another server. I was wondering what the best practices for accomplishing this. I have a class called ServerMonitor that has a start and stop. I want to put this all in the DAL because it has to do with the connection string and is called by a class I made called ConnectionStringFactory. I can't put it in the BLL or UI because it needs to be accessed by classes in the DAL.

The stop method in ServerMonitor closes the thread and releases resources. I was thinking the best way was to start the thread was to put it in the static constructor of the ServerMonitor but I don't know when to stop it. Is there a way to detect and application end event from the DAL or is there any way to know that the program stopped and I need to close the thread?

Comment: In the past I have implemented this at BLL to perform the mapping based on which UI layer asked for the data. This may not be appropriate for your application though. In my case I needed to connect to different databases depending on which UI connected to the BLL.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is stopped , you probably don't worry about to stop it. cause all the resource are suppose to be recycled by the .net framework.

It think it might be more appropriate to provide a method in your server monitor class , for the higher level UI thread to invoke, whenever they want to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I don't think that you need to close the thread.

I think that when your thread detects that the connection is closed, it should obtain the next server's connection string, verify it is available, then record that connection string in a static location within the DAL.

Also, to kick off your thread, you should definitely have it in a static constructor or, if it is hosted in IIS, kick it off in Application_Start of global.asax.

Another alternative is to kick off the process the first time that a request is made that requires the connection string (i.e. in the Connection String get accessor).